# why logstash grok regex group not work?

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack

step 1: this is my nginx log:

```
127.129.21.123  26/Jan/2016:23:35:39 +0800  GET /alipay/notify/1.0 HTTP/1.1 200 4   -   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36   0.009   127.0.0.1:9923  0.009   .
```

step 2 : this is my grok regex:

```
(?<result>(([.0-9a-zA-Z-:/]+\t)))
```

step 3: i debug on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and the result is :

```
{
  "result": [
    [
      "127.129.21.123\t"
    ]
  ]
}
```

last: why it shows the only first result?

please help me.

thank you very much!!

i change my question, because \t can't show on page correctly,now please visit image:

[image]

Comment: Could you fix the formatting of your nginx log, so that it can be pasted directly into grokdebug and yield that result?

Comment: my nginx log delimiter with '\t'  because of historical reason in project.When i paste into stackoverflow's editor and so on,'\t' was replaced by ' ' .

Comment: 127.129.21.123 26/Jan/2016:23:35:39 +0800 GET /alipay/notify/1.0?go=23 HTTP/1.1 200 4 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36(here has a '\t' but not show correctly)0.009 127.0.0.1:9923 0.009 .

Comment: this is my nginx format if nginx.conf:     log_format main '$remote_addr\t$time_local\t$request\t$status\t$body_bytes_sent\t$http_referer\t$http_user_agent\t$request_time\t$upstream_addr\t$upstream_response_time\t$pipe';

Comment: I change my question simplify and temporally, please see my image link:[http://ac913690.wiz03.com/share/s/2IAjqg1UbQ5m2Wf6he0PmGsV1xKa9S3tl4VP2qndGh0OWSo3](http://ac913690.wiz03.com/share/s/2IAjqg1UbQ5m2Wf6he0PmGsV1xKa9S3tl4VP2qndGh0OWSo3)

Comment: It is not possible, [the ticket is still open](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/27)

Comment: It is not possible, [the *grok filter: How to match one pattern multiple times?* ticket is still open](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/27). Try using a `mutate / gsub` with [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/11i2xj/1/) replacing with a space, and the just use [`split` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub).

Comment: Excellent! This is an elegant way to solve this ugly question. Although I have just overwrite a new pattern to solve it, I think I can try it in one day soon. Thank you.

Comment: @Linuxea Do not forget to post a solution once you get it working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think what you mean is asking me to post these discussions as an answer?
Then I'll do it

Comment: No, once you have code that works. I can post the idea and the regex with explanation myself - if you wish to accept.

Comment: What is the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of nice man(you can see in the question comments), I post their alternative answer as follows:

It is not possible, [the grok filter: How to match one pattern multiple times?](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/issues/27) ticket is still open.

Try using a `mutate / gsub` with [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/11i2xj/1/) replacing with a space, and the just use [split plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub).

thanks!